# How to configure nginx to support signalr3 under cloudflare?

Tags: asp.net, nginx, signalr, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am struggling with signalr3 and nginx reverse proxy configuration, my nginx cfg looks like this:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  my.customdomain.com;

location / {
  root /pages/my.customdomain.com;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

## send request back to kestrel ##
location /proxy/ {
 proxy_pass  http://xxxxxxxxxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/;

 proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
 proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

What do I miss here?

When I browse my page, I receive OK for

```
GET /proxy/notifications/negotiate
```

and

```
GET /proxy/notifications?id=uFQtMDg1dXib6LGvUssQhQ
```

but 404 for POST

```
POST proxy/notifications?id=uFQtMDg1dXib6LGvUssQhQ
```

pls halp!

ps. my Hub is very simple...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{

}
```

Comment: Does the POST work when you hit the service directly using curl?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no It does not work. I tried with fiddler and curl. same result 404

Comment: I mean skip nginx and directly hit the service, because if POST doesn't work directly then why should it work with NGINX?

Comment: @TarunLalwani on localhost it works fine (no nginx, pure kestrel)

Comment: Can you share nginx access and error logs? And also result of `curl -v -X POST .....` in your question?

Comment: @TarunLalwani please find https://gist.github.com/kwojciechowski/142b8882d004b3d44e7b66c2c7669c6c  I have attached fiddler request and response, nginx access log and error log in the debug mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173615/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-aph5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a websocket based app so you need additional nginx config

```
location / { 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true; 
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080; 
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off; 
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
    proxy_redirect off; 
}
```